# How to address many ellipses with different name in c# with for loop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have many ellipse with different name that started from `ball1` to `ball100`.
How can I have access to them with `for` loop to change some attributes of them in c# code

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Could you show an example of what code you already have, and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Add them to an array or list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for traversing on the list or array you can use `foreach` instead of `for` loop.

for example:

```
foreach (var item in ellipse)
{
   // In there you has access to each member of your list or array
   Console.WriteLine(item.Name)
}
```